# Split the contents of a cell and create a new list

Tags: r

I'm having trouble working out the following, and I think I'm suppose to use "seperate" or "split", but I can't seem to get it to populate properly.  I've clearly not understood something about how dataframes are manipulated...

I have a dataframe similar to below:

```
Team,                Result
Ken,                 5
Ken + Sam,           6
Taylor + Michael,    8
Michael + Frank,     7
Sebastian,           4
Taylor + Sam,        8
```

I am trying to split the cells that contain a " + " but try as I might I firstly end up with "Taylor,,,Michael" and "Michael,,,Frank" etc and then I can't seem to figure out how to create a new list of all the team members and then transform that list into a horizontal list eg:

First:

```
Team Members
Ken
Ken
Sam
Taylor
Michael
Michael
Frank
Sebastian
Taylor
Sam
```

Second:

```
Ken,Ken,Sam,Taylor,Michael,Michael,Frank,Sebastian,Taylor,Sam
```

Any help or tips where I could look would be greatly appreciated.  Everytime I think I'm getting somewhere with R, I end up in circles for hours and hours on what feels like a really simple task.

Comment: Try `unlist(strsplit(df$Team, split = " + ", fixed = TRUE))`. This will give you a character vector.

Comment: Thanks @markus - I knew I was doing something stupid, I had fixed = FALSE.  Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you still want to link the team members to the results, I'd suggest:

```
library(dplyr)    
df <- data.frame(team=c("A", "A+B", "C", "C+D"), result=c(1,2,3,4))
memberList <- df %>% separate(team, into=c("member1", "member2"), sep = "\\+") %>% gather(key = "MemberNumber", value = "Name", member1:member2 ) %>% filter(!is.na(Name))
```

Hope this helps!